# Validate integer values with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com) and I need to define a schema like the following:

```
const QuestionSchema = new Schema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    number: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }
});
```

I need to validate that the `number` field is an integer value. I have seen a couple plugins for that, e.g: [mongoose-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-integer):

```
const validateInteger = require('mongoose-integer');
const QuestionSchema = new Schema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    number: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        integer: true
    }
});
QuestionSchema.plugin(validateInteger);
```

But I'd prefer not using any third party libraries. Is there any other way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can add a [custom validator](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators) for `number`:

```
number: {
  type     : Number,
  required : true,
  unique   : true,
  validate : {
    validator : Number.isInteger,
    message   : '{VALUE} is not an integer value'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try using getters and setters for that:

```
number: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    integer: true,
    get: v => Math.round(v),
    set: v => Math.round(v),
}
```