# Mongoose Enum Number

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, enums

I need to get enum values of field in schema

I have schema:

```js
let adminSchema = new Schema({
 login: {
  type: String,
  unique: true,
  required: true,
  minlength: 5,
  maxlength: 300
 },
 hashedPassword: {
  type: String
 },
 role: {
  type: Number,
  enum: [0, 1, 2],
  default: 1
 },
 salt: {
  type: String
 }
});

module.exports.Admin = Admin;
module.exports.roleEnum = Admin.schema.path('role').enumValues;
console.log(module.exports.roleEnum);
```

console log -> undefined

but if i change role field type to String

```js
let adminSchema = new Schema({
 login: {
  type: String,
  unique: true,
  required: true,
  minlength: 5,
  maxlength: 300
 },
 hashedPassword: {
  type: String
 },
 role: {
  type: String,
  enum: ['0', '1', '2'],
  default: '1'
 },
 salt: {
  type: String
 }
});

module.exports.Admin = Admin;
module.exports.roleEnum = Admin.schema.path('role').enumValues;
console.log(module.exports.roleEnum);
```

console log -> ['0', '1', '2'];

How i can get enum array in Number type??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To specify a range of numeric values, you can define `min` and `max` values in the schema:

```
role: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    max: 2,
    default: 1
},
```

Docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema-number-js).

To also require that the values are integers, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711302/validate-integer-values-with-mongoose).

Answer (score 6):

The enums here are basically String objects. They can be Numbers

- All SchemaTypes have the built-in required validator.The required validator uses the SchemaType's checkRequired() function to determine if the value satisfies the required validator.
- Numbers have enum, min and max validators.
- Strings have enum, match, maxlength and minlength validators.

[Reference](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#numbers)

Answer (score 2):

You can get integer enums in `schema.path('some_path').options.enum;`
as mentioned in Docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schemanumberoptions_SchemaNumberOptions-enum)