# Is it possible to define the range of integer values in a Number field in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

```js
      slider_value: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
      },
```

This is the Mongoose schema for one of the fields in my MongoDB model.

Is it possible to specify the acceptable integer values in this field?

for example, this field may only accept the integers from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [min and max](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#numbers) validators, and you should also check for [isInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711302/validate-integer-values-with-mongoose)

```
slider_value: {
  type: Number,
  required: false,
  min: 1,
  max: 10,
  validate : {
    validator : Number.isInteger,
    message   : '{VALUE} is not an integer value'
  }
},
```

Comment: What is the acceptable values are [1, 4, 10]?

Comment: Do you mean enum?

Comment: does enum only work for string values? or can it for for integers as well?

Comment: @freelionsntigersfromcages https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303758/mongoose-enum-number

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`min` and `max`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#:%7E:text=default%20populate%20options-,Number,-min%3A%20Number%2C%20creates) validators:

```
slider_value: {
  type: Number,
  required: false,
  min: 1,
  max: 10
},
```